# Restore my system to factory settings

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, multi-boot, restore, sony-vaio

I have SONY VAIO with windows 7 pre installed. I have installed the UBUNTU in other partition to work as dual boot. I am trying now to restore the factory settings with ALT + F10 which is not working any more. Each time its giving me screen to choose operating system. How do I restore my system now?

The restore partition is still there and I have not deleted it. I did check it and SONY VIAO comes with restore partition as I have paid windows 7 in my laptop.

Comment: If the Sony VAIO instructions say that ALT + F10 should work, and its not working, then a factory setting restoration isn't possible.  The good news you can simply install Windows 7 over the current instalation of Ubuntu and merge the additional partitions if you want to get the same effect.

Comment: If its the original install of Windows 7, is there a Vaio Recovery Wizard in the control panel? If so, have you tried using it? Or how about just tapping F10 during boot? Does that bring up a recovery menu?

Comment: @Ramhound I will try to by reinstalling win 7

Comment: @Charlie I tried with F10 also

Comment: You said Alt + F10. Sony's site states F10 only. Just wanted to verify that.

Comment: for my series its Alt + F10 but I tried both and neither works